# STL + Ordered set + without duplicates

Tags: c++, collections, stl, duplicates, std

I need to have an ordered set of values without duplicates.
So, what is the fast/best method :

1 - Create a vector, sort it and remove duplicates ?
2 - Use a kind of "sorted" vector (if it exists) ?

Which one can be the more efficient ?

Comment: Use a set and specify your own comparator.

Comment: Would [this solution](http://ideone.com/F0V42m) work for you?

Comment: What kind of 'ordered' do you mean?  Keep insertion order?

Answer (score 18):

Why wouldn't you use a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)?

Comment: What if the order he wants is different from the set's sorting function?

Comment: You can define your own sorting function in that case.

Comment: Let me rephrase it: what if the order he wants (for instance, order of insertion) is different from the sorting function which determines the unicity of the elements in the set.

Comment: What if the specific order of elements is important as well as the fact that no two elements can be the same? I am in a situation right now where I NEED to maintain and observe a specific order.

Comment: @LB, there's a number of approaches.  1) keep data in two structures (e.g. a vector and an unordered_set -- the set would let you look up potential dupes quickly, the vector would preserve order).  2) keep data in one container that maintains the property you want (e.g. a vector) and just binary search that before each insert.  Choices here depends a lot on the amount of data and when that data is inserted/queried/etc.

Comment: @Joe thanks, it turned out I only needed to construct the containers and not modify them afterwards, so I settled with privately inheriting std::vector and selectively publicizing members.

Answer (score 6):

If you are going to load the list once then use it multiple times then using std::vector instead of std::set will probably be more efficient in memory usage and iterating through it.

If you are going to continually add and remove elements you should definitely use std::set.

For general purpose use std::set because it is less work (building the vector requires you to sort and remove duplicates after you have finished appending all the elements), unless you have a particular need for efficiency in low memory-use or some other performance hit that indicates vector is required.

Answer (score 5):

Use std::set. It's ordered, and it does not allow duplicates.

The only downside is that you don't get random access to the elements though this was not specified as a requirement.

Comment: It doesn't remove, it doesn't insert at all.

Comment: That is correct and what I meant. I'll edit the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Interesting that I recently got a downvote for this. I would be interested in knowing why as it appears to be correct as far as I know.

Comment: "Ordered" seems to mean different things to you and to computer science. `std::set` is an unordered container because it doesn't preserve the order in which items are inserted. `vector` and `deque` are ordered.

Comment: @Violet Giraffe See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833938/c-stdset-iteration-order-by-specification

Answer (score 1):

The efficiency will depend on the ratio of insertions/accesses you have (i.e., the number of times you'll need to sort your vector). If performance is really important there, I suggest that you try both approaches and use the fastest one for a real case of application usage.

Note: `std::set` is not a sorted vector because it is not contiguous in memory (it is a tree).
The "sorted vector" you want is a heap over `std::vector`. See: http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/14-7.html.

Answer (score 1):

There is always [Loki::AssocVector](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00025.html)

Otherwise you can easily roll your own:

- use a `std::vector` or `std::deque` as the base container
- use `lower_bound` / `upper_bound` / `equal_range` and `binary_search` generic algorithms to look up an object
- also `inplace_merge` is great when you already know that the value is not present

But really, use a `std::set` :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if I need a quick one-off, I'll use both a set *and* a list together, and do something like [this](https://ideone.com/g9W0fJ):

```
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // set prevents dupes, list preserves order
    set<string> theset;
    list<set<string>::iterator> thelist;
    
    // insertion is like this:
    auto insert = [&] (const string &str) {
        auto inserted = theset.insert(str);
        if (inserted.second)
            thelist.push_back(inserted.first);
    };

    // then, for example:
    insert("zebra");       // first zebra
    insert("chair a");     // first chair a
    insert("desk");        // first desk
    insert("desk");
    insert("chair b");     // first chair b
    insert("chair a");
    insert("chair a");
    insert("table");       // first table
    insert("chair a");
    insert("xylophone");   // first xylophone
    insert("zebra");
    
    // access can be done like:
    for (auto istr : thelist)
        cout << *istr << endl;
    
}
```

You don't have to use the lambda there, it was just easier to type for this example. Anyways, that outputs:

```
zebra
chair a
desk
chair b
table
xylophone
```

---

The key points here are:

- `set::insert` returns a useful `<iterator,bool>` pair, where the first value is the new iterator (if inserted) or the existing iterator (if not), and the second value is true (if inserted) or false (if not).
- `set::insert` doesn't invalidate any other iterators in the set, whether an insertion happened or not.
- We can use a `set` to quickly avoid duplicates, and a `list` to preserve order.
- Store the set's iterators in the list just to avoid copying values.

And the implementation, then, is:

- Construct a `set` for values (for dupe checks) and a `list` of iterators (for order preservation).
- When inserting, always try to add to the set, but only add to the list if it wasn't already in the set (i.e. if it's not a dupe).
- When accessing, just remember its a list of iterators, not a list of values, so a `list<set::iterator>::iterator` does need two levels of dereferencing to access the value.

The pros and cons are:

- Pro: Easy to implement.
- Pro: Works.
- Pro: Doesn't copy values.
- Pro: Uses uniqueness semantics of a plain old `set`.
- Con: Can complicate access syntax.
- Con: Must iterate over entire list once if you want to convert it to a list of values.
- Con: You've got to lug two containers around.
- Con: Isn't fancy enough to have its own transparent container interface, i.e. it is not, itself, a container.

Options you have to enhance this and reduce some of the cons, at the cost of having to write extra code:

- Stick both containers in a `class`/`struct` with an `insert` method and whatever else you want, to make carrying it around a bit easier.
- Return `.second` from your insert function if you want the caller to be able to know if it was inserted or not (e.g. maybe you have to delete things if they aren't inserted or something).
- Template said `class`/`struct` with support for whatever value type. You could also template the unique and ordered container types, if you want to use other types of sets or lists.
- Wrap the whole thing in a conformant *Container* interface, if you'd like all the features of a proper STL container.

Also, you can find ordered set implementations out there (some of the other answers here provide links). I use the one I described here when I'm just coding things quickly; it's simple enough that it's usually quicker for me to just do this than it is to go get an existing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what efficiency you want. If you want something that's "just fast", use std::set<> (as others already suggested).

However, if you need chache coherency or to keep things in a vector (aligned memory guaranteed) instead of a set (nothing guaranteed, implemented as a tree if I remember correctly) then you'll have to ust directly std::vector combined with some standard algorithms that assume the container you provide is already sorted (then making the check faster), like [std::binary_search()](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/).

Answer (score 0):

Insert into a set takes log(n). And the sort is free.

Insert into a vector (push_back) takes constant time. Sorting a vector takes n*log(n). 
But you still need to remove duplicates.

If you insert in one go and then sort, you can consider also vector. If you insert frequently set is the right one.

Comment: Inserting into the set N elements is thus N*logN which means the same complexity as building the vector. Removing duplicates if done efficiently is O(N) so the whole process is still O(N log N )

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .h or .hpp:

```
struct TestWithTime
{
    TestWithTime(unsigned long long timeSecs) : m_timeSecs(timeSecs) {}

    unsigned long long m_timeSecs;
}

struct OrderedByTime
{
    bool operator() (const TestWithTime* first,  const TestWithTime* second) const
    {
        // Important: if the time is equal
        if (first->m_timeSecs == second->m_timeSecs)
        {
            // then compare the pointers
            return first < second;
        }
        return first->m_timeSecs < second->m_timeSecs;
    }
};

typedef std::set<TestWithTime*, OrderedByTime> OrderedDataByTime;
```

Now you can use your OrderedDataByTime set !!

Answer (score -1):

Ordered set is basically a policy based data structure in g++ that keeps the unique elements in sorted order. It's close to [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) data structure in STL that performs operations in `log(n)` complexity and performs two additional operations also in log(n) complexity. :)

- `order_of_key (n)` : Number of items that smaller than `n`
- `find_by_order(n)` : `n`-th element in a set (in 0 indexed)

for more details, [follow this link](https://github.com/shiningflash/advance-data-structure/blob/master/ordered_set.cpp)